# SwiftEntryKit: dismissing entry by tap on background

Tags: ios, swift

I use SwiftEntryKit to display view controller (custom pop up) with attributes.
I added dark blur for background by:

```
attributes.screenBackground = .visualEffect(style: .dark)
```

And display vc:

```
SwiftEntryKit.display(entry: vc, using: attributes)
```

How can I add dismissing entry by tap on the background?
I can't find similar settings in SwiftEntryKit documentation or I don't understand where I need to add TapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often happens - it is worth asking a question and the answer is found on its own =)

```
attributes.screenInteraction = .dismiss
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need to ask and then the answer will somehow appear by itself when you "look again"